# Flutter: Index out of range error, List Element Availability In Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, web

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import '../data/monthly_cpi.dart';
import '../model/monthlycpi.dart';

class MonthlyCPIList extends StatefulWidget {
  MonthlyCPIList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MonthlyCPIListState createState() => _MonthlyCPIListState();
}

class _MonthlyCPIListState extends State<MonthlyCPIList> {
  List<MonthlyCPI> monthlyCPIList = [];

  void getMonthlyCPIfromApi() async {
    var url = Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:8000/');
    final response = await http.get(url);
    Iterable decoded_response = json.decode(response.body);
    monthlyCPIList = decoded_response.map((model) => MonthlyCPI.fromJson(model)).toList();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getMonthlyCPIfromApi();
    print(monthlyCPIList.elementAt(0).cpi_description);
  }
```

My code is above. What I'm not understanding is if I put the statement:

`print(monthlyCPIList.elementAt(0).cpi_description);` at the end of the `getMonthlyCPIfromAPI()` method, the element prints fine.

However, if I place the print statement at the end of the `initState()` method, I get an error:

Index out of range, no indices are valid: 0. I feel like I'm missing something fundamental about the context flutter sets around lists (i.e. local vs global etc.). Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `getMonthlyCPIfromApi()` is an async function internally but for `initState` it's just another function call, hence initState code doesn't wait for `getMonthlyCPIfromApi()` to complete and then execute    `print(monthlyCPIList.elementAt(0).cpi_description);`
- `initState` itself is not an async function, if you try to add async and await on `initState` you will get errors, print statement would not have thrown any error if the code was something like this **which is not possible since its an overridden function**

  ```
       INCORRECT CODE (HYPOTHETICAL EXAMPLE)
       @override
       void initState() async {
             super.initState();
             await getMonthlyCPIfromApi();
             print(monthlyCPIList.elementAt(0).cpi_description);
       }
  ```
- To make your code work what can be done is

  ```
       getMonthlyCPIfromApi().then((value) {
       print(monthlyCPIList.elementAt(0).cpi_description);});
  ```

Comment: This was helpful thank you. My background is in data engineering, analytics, data science, etc. so I'm still wrapping my head around async as a concept.